# Python HTMLParser printing out blank lines

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm playing around with python's HTMLParser and having an issue with it printing out blank lines.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
def handle_data(self, data):
     print "Encountered some data  :", data

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
url = 'http://www.ngccoin.com/price-guide/us/flying-eagle-cents-pscid-16-desig-ms'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' :"Magic Browser"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed( html )
```

My issue is when it hits a data section it prints out just new lines as well as actual data.  MY output looks a lot like:

```
Encountered some data  :

Encountered some data  : Official Grading Service of
Encountered some data  :

Encountered some data  :

Encountered some data  :
```

How should I go about getting it to ignore those lines with just a new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply have it ignore those lines with just a new line:

```
def handle_data(self, data):
    if data == '\n':
        return
    print "Encountered some data  :", data
```

Or, have it ignore any data consisting of only whitespace:

```
def handle_data(self, data):
    if not data.strip():
        return
    print "Encountered some data  :", data
```

Comment: I attempted to ignore anything with `\n` originally and that was unsuccessful, but the `data.strip()` solution worked like a charm.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because data passes one line at a time, Data needs to be aggregated as such:

```
def handle_data(self, data):
  self.cell += data
```

Then later in the close tag....

```
def handle_endtag(self, tag):
  self.somevariable = self.cell.strip()
  self.cell = ''
```

Stripping the newlines at the end preserves the formatting of the data.